# JAVA HttpClient 401 after login

Tags: java, android, http, web, httpclient

I nube in java, and in web programming. But i have to write application for android, that working whith http.
I wrote class for http requests, and have one problem: error 401 after authorization, when I send another requests.
What can it bee and how can I fix it?
Thanks for the help

```
public void SendRequest(final String url)  {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                URI website = null;
                try {
                    website = new URI(baseUri+url);
                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
                }
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
                request.setURI(website);
                HttpResponse response = null;
                try {
                    response = client.execute(request, localContext);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
                }
                if (response != null)
                {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    try {
                        InputStream is = entity.getContent();
                        httpEvent.HttpResponseArrived(convertStreamToString(is),response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }

public void Login(String login, String password, boolean isRemember)
    {
        String mess = "logon?username="+login+"&password="+password+"&remember="+ Boolean.toString(isRemember);

            SendRequest(mess);
            httpEvent = new HttpHandler()
            {
                @Override
                public void HttpResponseArrived(String data, int code)
                {
                    String mess = "Error";
                    switch (code)
                    {
                        case 401:
                            mess = "Incorrect login/password";
                            break;
                        case 200:
                            mess = "";
                            break;
                    }
                    events.LoginArrived(Boolean.valueOf(data), mess);
                }
            };
    }
```

Comment: Have you sent your session id so that the server recognizes you?

Comment: I jast sent login and password:)

Comment: When you login to something, a session is saved on the server to remember you. A cookie is probably sent back which you should use in your future requests.

Comment: I tryed somethind like this, but it doesn't works: CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
HttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
httpContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

Comment: Did you even ask yourself what those lines of code do? How would any of that help?

Comment: I tryed attach this context to the request, but yes, now I see my mistake

Comment: the most interecting, that this lines of code helped me... the problem was in one android device. The other works fine